# Working with BotFramework on Xamarin Forms

Tags: websocket, xamarin.forms, botframework, direct-line-botframework

So I'm using DirectLine client to work with the BotFramework on Xamarin Forms. I was able to start a conversation and according to the documentation [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/#navtitle) I should connect to the stream's url which comes in the initial POST request to start a conversation. 
Now, the documentation states that I should receive an 'https://' regular URL, however I receive a 'uwss://' URL to work with a websocket. Currently there are no websocket libraries available for Xamarin (not a useful I have seen at least)
How can I continue? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked to clearly shows that you have both options available to receive messages. Either use the web socket which will stream data to you, or repeatedly call standard HTTP GET requests to poll the data. It describes in detail how you form the GET request and how you authenticate with a bearer token.

In case you DO want to use the web socket approach, I have successfully used [Square.SocketRocket](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Square.SocketRocket/) for WebSockets (over HTTPS).

Comment: Hi irreal, it states that I have both options but however when I try to ues GET requests the service doesn't reply. I tried to use both tokens and and App secret but without success

Comment: So I was dumb enough to forget adding the Content-Type in my POST request and that was why I could never chat with my Bot. At the end I could communicate using POST and GET only, ditching the webSocket approach.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself here. The Bot Framework team made me realize it is not necessary to call the URL that comes in the result from the "Start a conversation" POST request. That is only needed if one plans to use a WebSocket to hold the conversation.
As of today, I have not found a Xamarin Forms working WebSocket client, but there are good WebSocket clients for Xamarin iOS or Xamarin Android.